# jquery not trapping keyCode

Tags: jquery

I have the following as part of some code - you can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/73c3X/1/

```
    if (txt.val().length >= 10 && (event.keyCode != 46 || event.keyCode != 8 || event.keyCode != 9)) {
        alert(txt.val().length + "keycode = " + event.keyCode);
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.onlynumbers').text("10 digits in mobile").show(200);
    }
```

The idea is to prevent someone entering more than 10 digits and display a message.

I would have expected the line

```
if(txt.val().length >= 10 && (event.keyCode != 46 || event.keyCode != 8 || event.keyCode != 9))
```

to allow a tab, backspace or delete to be used, however as you can see in the fiddle, they get past the if statement and trigger the alert - which will even show that that the length = 10 and the keyCode = 9.

It looks fine to me, obviously it isn't.  Am I missing something or will this be a DOH! moment?

Comment: hi was having a bit of a play with this as haven't really worked too much with jquery, I ignored your html etc and [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/73c3X/16/) what I came up with. Some things I noticed was `esc` was only identified on `keyup` and the keyboard on my laptop differs slightly in keycoding from [this](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx) resource which I think has something to do the number pad (or lack of in my case). Hopes this helps in someway

Comment: Thanks Tom appreciate your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
if (txt.val().length >= 10 && event.keyCode != 46 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 9) {
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if(txt.val().length >= 10 && (event.keyCode != 46 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 9))
```

in the beggining of code as you want to catch ALL but those three. Also, don't forget the arrows as they can be used to move and edit the number.

Comment: Yep, arrows were coming, just wanted to clear this hurdle - +1 for the suggestion